# Bind ToggleGroup bidirectionally in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Imagine having an enum defining mouse-modes:

```
public enum MouseMode {
SELECTION,
EDITING,
DELETING }
```

And imagine having a toggle-group made of 3 buttons:

```
    ToggleButton selection = new ToggleButton("Select");
    ToggleButton editing = new ToggleButton("Edit");
    ToggleButton deleting = new ToggleButton("Delete");
    ToggleGroup mouseSelection = new ToggleGroup();
```

I want a field `MouseMode currentMode` to be bidirectionally linked to the toggle-group. Whenever a toggle is set, currentMode is switched accordingly but also if some external process changes currentMode (maybe a key press) then the togglegroup adapts accordingly.

I can do this with 2 listeners but I wonder if there is a way to create a custom bidirectional map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this directly. While a general-purpose

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional(Property<S> property1, Property<T> property2, Function<S,T> mapping, Function<T,S> inverseMapping)
```

might make a good addition to the API, even that wouldn't help in this case as the `ToggleGroup`'s `selectedProperty` is read only (since selection needs to be handled when each `Toggle`'s `setSelected(...)` method is invoked, as well as by the `ToggleGroup`'s `selectedProperty`).

Using a couple of listeners is the way to go in this case.

The closest thing to the "custom bidirectional map" is the

```
Bindings.bindBiDirectional(StringProperty stringProperty, ObjectProperty<T> otherProperty, StringConverter<T> converter)
```

method. In the case where you have an (writeable) `ObjectProperty<S>` and (writeable) `ObjectProperty<T>` you can in theory use two bidirectional bindings and an intermediate `StringProperty` to bind them together. In practice, this is almost always more code than just using two listeners, and is also less efficient.

Comment: thanks. Yeah, I am working on a customzied Bindings.bindBidirectional(Property<S> property1, Property<T> property2, Function<S,T> mapping, Function<T,S> inverseMapping), with some luck it'll work out fine. But you are right, selectedProperty is readOnly so that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully made use of the [ToggleGroupValue](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/10.0/jfxtras-controls/src/main/java/jfxtras/scene/control/ToggleGroupValue.java) class in the JFXtras project.

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    Child myChild = new Child();
    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle( "ToggleGroupValue Example" );
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        int rowIndex = 0;
        gridPane.add( new Label("Nickname: "), 0, rowIndex );
        
        ToggleGroupValue toggleGroupValue = new ToggleGroupValue();
        rowIndex = createAddRadioButtons( gridPane, rowIndex, toggleGroupValue );
        
        gridPane.add( new Label("Selected Nickname: "), 0, rowIndex );
        Label selectedNickNameValueLabel = new Label();
        gridPane.add( selectedNickNameValueLabel, 1, rowIndex );
        
        myChild.nicknameProperty().bindBidirectional( toggleGroupValue.valueProperty() );
        selectedNickNameValueLabel.textProperty().bind( toggleGroupValue.valueProperty() );
        
        stage.setScene( new Scene( gridPane, 300, 100 ) );
        stage.show();
    }

    private int createAddRadioButtons( GridPane gridPane, int rowIndex, ToggleGroupValue toggleGroupValue ) {
        RadioButton radioButtonPunkin = new RadioButton();
        radioButtonPunkin.setUserData( "Punkin" );
        RadioButton radioButtonLittleBoy = new RadioButton();
        radioButtonLittleBoy.setUserData( "Little Boy" );
        RadioButton radioButtonBuddy = new RadioButton();
        radioButtonBuddy.setUserData( "Buddy" );
        List<RadioButton> radioButtons = Arrays.asList( radioButtonPunkin, radioButtonLittleBoy, radioButtonBuddy );
        for ( RadioButton radioButton : radioButtons ) {
            toggleGroupValue.add( radioButton, radioButton.getUserData() );
            radioButton.setText( radioButton.getUserData().toString() );
            gridPane.add( radioButton, 1, rowIndex++ );
        }
        return rowIndex;
    }

    private static class Child {
        private StringProperty nickname = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public StringProperty nicknameProperty() {
            return nickname;
        }
        public String getNickname() {
            return nickname.get();
        }
        public void setNickname( String notesProperty ) {
            this.nickname.set( notesProperty );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of javafx example application]

Comment: Seems to be part of 8.0 too http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-controls/jfxtras/scene/control/ToggleGroupValue.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Java bean property adapter, but you can just use the last line of this code and bind it.

```
JavaBeanObjectProperty<fooEnum> property = null;
    try {
        property = new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<fooEnum>().bean(fooBean).name(fooField).build();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    property.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("Property value changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    });
BindingUtils.bindToggleGroupToProperty(fooToggleGroup, property);
```

You need to have a small BindingUtils class for ToggleGroup.

```
public final class BindingUtils {

private BindingUtils() {
}

public static <T> void bindToggleGroupToProperty(final ToggleGroup toggleGroup, final ObjectProperty<T> property) {
    // Check all toggles for required user data
    toggleGroup.getToggles().forEach(toggle -> {
        if (toggle.getUserData() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The ToggleGroup contains at least one Toggle without user data!");
        }
    });
    // Select initial toggle for current property state
    for (Toggle toggle : toggleGroup.getToggles()) {
        if (property.getValue() != null && property.getValue().equals(toggle.getUserData())) {
            toggleGroup.selectToggle(toggle);
            break;
        }
    }
    // Update property value on toggle selection changes
    toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        property.setValue((T) newValue.getUserData());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by [tunabot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25061488/11235449). Instead of using `RadioButton`, this answer will use `ToogleButton`, and to make it look more beautiful, we will use `SegmentedButton` from [ControlsFX](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx). We can bind bidirectional selected toggle button by using `valueProperty` from `ToggleGroupValue`.

There is a debug button that when we click this button the selected button will change to `DELETING` button.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jfxtras.scene.control.ToggleGroupValue;
import org.controlsfx.control.SegmentedButton;

public class ToggleBindingDemo extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<MouseMode> mouseModeObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(MouseMode.SELECTION);;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        ToggleGroupValue<MouseMode> toggleGroupValue = new ToggleGroupValue<>();

        ToggleButton selection = new ToggleButton("Selection");
        selection.setUserData(MouseMode.SELECTION);
        selection.setToggleGroup(toggleGroupValue);

        ToggleButton editing = new ToggleButton("Editing");
        editing.setUserData(MouseMode.EDITING);
        editing.setToggleGroup(toggleGroupValue);

        ToggleButton deleting = new ToggleButton("Deleting");
        deleting.setUserData(MouseMode.DELETING);
        deleting.setToggleGroup(toggleGroupValue);

        toggleGroupValue.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(mouseModeObjectProperty);
        mouseModeObjectProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<MouseMode>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MouseMode> observable, MouseMode oldValue, MouseMode newValue){
                System.out.println("MouseMode: " + newValue);
            }
        });

        SegmentedButton segmentedButton = new SegmentedButton(selection, editing, deleting);
        segmentedButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroupValue);
        Button debugButton = new Button("Debug");
        debugButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> handleDebugClick());

        VBox vBox = new VBox(segmentedButton, debugButton);
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        StackPane root = new StackPane(vBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    void handleDebugClick(){
        mouseModeObjectProperty.set(MouseMode.DELETING);
    }

    public enum MouseMode{
        SELECTION,
        EDITING,
        DELETING
    }
}
```

[image]